# Is it possible to rename the IDs in Google Analytic's Enhanced Ecommerce?

Tags: google-analytics

What I'd like to do is change the names of certain fields for better tracking for my website. I don't have a tax, and organization doesn't ship anything. So I was wondering if I could change those fields to something else like shipping -> gifts, and track for any additional funds donated part of their initial donation, that would be awesome. I've tried googling this but there's so much information to sort through that so far I haven't found an answer.

Google's provided code

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y');
ga('require', 'ec');
ga('set', '&cu', 'EUR');              // Set tracker currency to Euros

ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
  id: 'T12345',
  affiliation: 'Google Store - Online',
  revenue: '28.03',
  tax: '2.14',
  shipping: '4.00',
});

ga('send', 'pageview');
```

The code I'd like to use

```
<script>
    var formatDollar = '[[S120:dc:giftAmount]]';
        formatDollar.split(",").join("");
    var dollarAmt = formatDollar.split(",").join("");

(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y');
ga('require', 'ec');
ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
  id: '[[S120:dc:transactionID]]',
  affiliation: '[[S120:dc:donationFormName]]',

      revenue: dollarAmt,
      category: '[[S120:dc:giftType]]',
      currency: 'CAD'
      gifts: '[[S120:dc:additionalGifts]]',
    });
    ga('ecommerce:send');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Would this work? (I know my UA code needs to be fixed I just forgot what the code was so i just put whatever).

I would test it, but right now the person in charge of all the GA stuff just left for the week, so I won't know if it works or not until they come back (no access to the GA account).

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the name, but GA won't recognise those names and know what to do with them. If some parameters don't apply, like `shipping`, then you could simply leave them out; only `id` is required. Or if you want to include other parameters, then they would need to be done as custom dimensions:

```
ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
   id: '[[S120:dc:transactionID]]',
   affiliation: '[[S120:dc:donationFormName]]',
   revenue: dollarAmt,
   category: '[[S120:dc:giftType]]',
   currency: 'CAD',
   dimension1: '[[S120:dc:additionalGifts]]',
});
```

where `dimension1` is configured as a product-scoped custom dimension and contains the value for your gifts.

Comment: Nyuen! you've come to my aid again. So if `ID` is the only thing required, can I use the `id` of my additionalGifts field? or were talking about the GA `id`s? Either way I guess it won't matter since now i can just use dimensions. Is there a limit to the number of dimensions we can use per tracking?

Comment: `id` is the transaction ID. Might want to double check that a dimension can be included in the `purchase` action... I know it can be done for the other actions, like `addProduct`, and `addImpressions`, but if you can't add a dimension for the purchase, then you'd just have to leave it out.

Comment: okay great! this more than enough information to get me going. thanks again nyuen!